# Help with proof of $\langle\chi,\psi\rangle=\delta_{\chi,\psi}$ with $\chi$ and $\psi$ characters of a group.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

In *The Symmetric Group*, we are presented with the following theorem

> Let $\chi$ and $\psi$ be irreducible characters of a group $G$. Then $$\langle\chi,\psi\rangle=\delta_{\chi,\psi}\tag{1} $$

In the proof he writes the following: Suppose $\chi,\psi$ are the characters of matrix representations $A,B$ of degrees $d,f$, respectively and let $X=(x_{i,j})$ be a $d\times f$ matrix of indeterminates and consider the matrix
$$\tag{2}
Y=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}A(g)XB(g^{-1})
$$
The author then shows that
$$\tag{3}
    Y=\begin{cases}
    0, & \text{if } A \not\cong B, \\
    c I_d, & \text{if } A \cong B.
    \end{cases}
$$
When we consider $\chi\neq \psi$, then eq. (3) implies that
$$\tag{4}
\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{k, l} \sum_{g \in G} a_{i, k}(g) x_{k, l} b_{l, j}\left(g^{-1}\right)=0
$$
for all $i,j$. The author writes that "*If this polynomial is to be zero, the coefficient of each $x_{k,l}$ must also be zero, so*
$$\tag{5}
\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} a_{i, k}(g) b_{l, j}\left(g^{-1}\right)=0
$$
*for all $i,j,k,l$*". What I do not understand about this is that it assumes that $x_{k,l}$ are nonzero (because if they are zero, then eq. (4) says nothing about $a_{i,k}$ and $b_{l,j}$). So the question is

> why does he assume that $x_{k,l}\ne 0?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, it comes from the fact that the matrix $X=(x_{i,j})$ is a matrix of indeterminants, so these $x_{i,j}$ are just variables, and the quantity $Y$ will be a polynomial in the variables $x_{i,j}$, so what is being said is if $\chi\neq \psi$, then we have that the polynomial $Y=0$, and the only way for a polynomial to be $0$ is for each of the coefficients to be $0$ which is how equation $5$ is derived. It is like saying let us assume we have a quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$, but if we assume that this polynomial is identically $0$ for any value of $x$, then we must conclude that $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.